# Set fixed position for buttons

Tags: html, css

I have this html code which I use with Bootstrap:

```
<div class="text-center offset-top-20">
    <input id="update" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update" /> &#160;
    <input id="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Cancel" />            
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/02jmwd85/1/

When I resize the web page and reduce the width the buttons are moved and the second goes below the first. Is there some way to to keep their position and keep them horizontally?

Comment: This is not a JSF problem. When having a question related to HTML and CSS code which is generated by a server side framework, then you should ask the question using the generated HTML and CSS code (which you can easily find by rightclick, *View Page Source* in webbrowser), instead of in the original server side code which the HTML/CSS experts may not understand at all. Once you get the answer from HTML/CSS experts, then all you need to do is to just rewrite the server side code in such way that it generates exactly the answered HTML/CSS instead.

Comment: By the way, "jsfiddle" only understands HTML/CSS/JS and absolutely not JSF or whatever server side framework. Moreover, in your demo link the buttons do not at all show up. So your demo link is unusable. It is "JS-fiddle" and certainly not "JSF-iddle" ;)

Answer (score 0):

The responsive design feature of Bootstrap allows the UI elements to automatically stack up one below the other on narrow screens.

This is a desirable feature in many scenarios.

This functionality can be overridden by custom style specified at the component level.

In the current scenario, the custom style can be applied to the `<div>` that encloses the two buttons - Update and Cancel to prevent those from stacking up.

This can be done by specifying a minimum width for the enclosing div.

**Here is an example:**

```
<div class="text-center offset-top-20" style="min-width: 500px">
    <input id="update" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update" /> &#160;
    <input id="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Cancel" />            
</div>
```

**How does the above solution prevent the buttons from stacking up?**

The custom style attribute - `style="min-width: 500px;"` makes sure that the enclosing div cannot become narrower than 500 pixels.

The 500 pixels of width will give enough room for both the buttons to stay side by side.

This will in turn prevent the buttons from stacking up.